# Bounding the integral of the derivative of an absolutely continuous function

Tags: calculus, inequality, continuity, absolute-continuity

Let $f:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$. If $f$ is differentiable I can write
$$
\int_a^bf'(x)dx \leq |b-a|\sup_{x\in[a,b]} |f'(x)|.
$$

I believe that a similar inequality should hold when $f$ is only [absolutely continuous](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Absolute_continuity) so that it is only differentiable almost everywhere. But in that case I'm not sure how to think of $\sup_{x\in[a,b]} |f'(x)|$. The function might not be differentiable at some points in $[a,b]$ but that should not affect the integral. Could I say that the $\sup$ is over the points where $f$ is differentiable? Is there a better way to write this?

Comment: note that $f'$ may not be integrable even if $f$ is differentiable everywhere so one has to be careful here; if $f$ is integrable the result is true with $||f||_{\infty}$ being the essential supremum

Comment: cf https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Essential_supremum_and_essential_infimum

Comment: notice that neither differentiability nor absolute continuity implies that $f'$ is (essentially) bounded.